# Avoid user interaction when connecting

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi-direct

is it possible to connect to a WiFi Direct device (write/read data back and forth) without any user interaction?

I've used the sample code from: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-98

which uses the following snippet:

```
    WiFiDirectConnectionParameters ConnectionParams = new WiFiDirectConnectionParameters();

    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var wfdDevice = await WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedDiscoveredDevice.DeviceInfo.Id, ConnectionParams).AsTask(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

However FromIdAsync opens a dialogue prompting the user to enter a pin or press a confirmation button which i want to avoid.

Comment: Hi, the user needs to confirm the device to be connected. This is the design of the UWP application. You must perform this confirmation step.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying